# Work with multi-diminutional array dynamically as UIImage array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage

I'm working on app to do paged photos inside scrollViews like in the photos app to swipe right to get the old photos and swipe left to get the new photos until the end of photos.

Alright,so i am getting the photos as a multi-diminutional from the web :

```
imageArray[indexPath.row][0] as? String
```

Thats in the `ViewController1` to show all the images in CollectionView .

When the user press on a photo i do segue and show the image larger in `ViewController2` so if swipe left it show the new photos and right to show the old photos which is stored in the array.

but i need to covert my two-dimensional array to one and use it dynamically to be something like this :

```
pageImages = [UIImage(named:"photo1.png")!,
    UIImage(named:"photo2.png")!,
    UIImage(named:"photo3.png")!,
    UIImage(named:"photo4.png")!,
    UIImage(named:"photo5.png")!]
```

how is it possible to do ?

i could say like :

`pageImages = [UIimage(named:thewholearray)]` ?

i tried first to convert to one-diminutional array but i failed :

```
var imageArray : NSArray = []

var mybigarray : NSArray = []
    for (var i=0; i<=self.imageArray.count; i++) {

        self.mybigarray = self.imageArray[i][0] as! NSArray

    }
```

which generate this casting error :

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x196806958) to 'NSArray' (0x196807308).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the map-function to extract the image names from your multi-dimensional array.

```
var imageNames:[String] = imageArray.map({
    $0[0] as! String
})
```

The map function iterates through all array entries like a for-in-loop.
The statement in the closure determines the new entry of your imageNames array.

**EDIT:**

If you don't use Swift-Arrays:

```
var imageNames:NSMutableArray = []
for image in imageArray{
    imageNames.addObject(image[0] as! String)
}
```

Comment: NSArray doesn't have a member called map ?

Comment: Great, one last thing if i need to use imageNames as UIImage array as my question how is it possible to do ?

Comment: imageNames.addObject(UIImage(named: "\\(image[0] as! String)")!)

Comment: @AaoIi, what I wrote will be images. I don't understand what else you want.

Comment: please clarify your question

Comment: @Caleb , when i used your code it generates a : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: Then what Caleb has written is your answer. You will get an array of UIImges with imageNames.addObject(UIImage(named: "\(image[0] as! String)")!)

Comment: @AaoIi, I probably have a typo. Daniel can you modify the answer above to include this and verify that it is written correctly?

Comment: @DanielHariri, No you've answered the half and it works fine and the other half is to add it as UIImage but its just generating the error . I'm trying to figure it out ! Thanks

Comment: I've used this code : `imageNames.addObject(image[0] as! String)` and i printed it, its working fine but when i tried to use this `imageNames.addObject(UIImage(named: "(image[0] as! String)")!) `  it generates fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: Ok, since UIImage(named:String) returns an optional and you unwrap it with  UIImage(named: "(image[0] as! String)")! it means that the image with the given name doesn't exist in your resources.

Comment: I'm getting the images from the web and its not stored inside my resources, using UIImage is needed to accomplish my app. you may check this following link where you can find the class called "PagedScrollViewController" : http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift, i just need to use imageNames array as the pageImages.

Comment: Do you already have the data of the images fetched from the web?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85007/discussion-between-aaoii-and-daniel-hariri).

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the tutorial and I think this will help with the answer from Daniel. Keep Daniel's Answer and use the URLs from the array with the extension.
Add this to create you images from a URL

```
extension UIImageView {
    public func imageFromUrl(urlString: String) {
        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
                (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if data != nil {
                    self.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
                else {
                    self.image = UIImage()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use this in the PagedImageScrollViewController:

```
newPageView.imageFromUrl(pageImages[page])
```

pageImages is your array of Strings.

Comment: Sure i will keep it , I am using SDWebImage library to show the images, so how is it possible to do it without the extension ? https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage , i tried to do like              `let newPageView = UIImageView(image: pageImages[page] as! UIImage)
            newPageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url)` but it says `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x196806958) to 'UIImage' (0x19746a698).`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the SDWebImage library. The error looks like it occurs because your pageImages is an array of strings and you're trying to set a String to an Image. I can look into the SDWebImage library some time later if you can't get a solution. Maybe you can manipulate the extension to fit your needs?